# Ruby Word Guessing Game

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I am new to Ruby and working with this hangman style word guessing game. I have 2 main issues. Here is what I am working with now:

```
class Word_game

  def initialize(word)
    @word = word.downcase 
    @display_word = "_ " * word.length
  end

  def guess_the_word(word_guess)
    word_guess.downcase 
    @word.split("").each_with_index do |word_letter, index|
        if word_guess == word_letter
          @display_word[index] = word_guess 
          p @display_word
          puts "You're getting somewhere! Keep trying!"
        end 
      end
        if !@word.include? (word_guess)
          puts "Nope, guess again..."
        end


  def win? 
    if @word == @display_word
      puts "Congratulations you won!!! You are the word master!!!"
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end 

  def lose?
    if @attempts == 0 
      puts "You lose!!"
      true 
    end 
  end 

puts "Welcome to the Word Guessing Game! Let's see if YOU have what it TAKES!!!"
puts "This is a 2 player game. "
puts "Player 1... please enter a word for Player 2 to guess!"
puts ">>"

game_word = gets.chomp 
game = Word_game.new(game_word)

attempts = 0
guessed_letters = []

  until @attempts == game_word.length 
    puts "Ok Player 2, Guess a letter! GO!!!"
     letter_guess = gets.chomp
        if guessed_letters.include? letter_guess
          puts "You already guessed that letter! Enter a new one."
          letter_guess = gets.chomp
        end
    guessed_letters << letter_guess
    game.guess_the_word(letter_guess)
    if game.win?
      attempts += 1 
    else game.lose? 
    end
  end
end
```

- First, the word progress should look like this if the word is hello:

  ```
   h _ e _ _ o
  ```
- Instead of this, the spaces are not in the right places and looks like this (an actual outcome of running my code):

.

```
Ok Player 2, Guess a letter! GO!!!
 h
"h _ _ _ _ "
You're getting somewhere! Keep trying!
Ok Player 2, Guess a letter! GO!!!
 o
"h _ o _ _ "
You're getting somewhere! Keep trying!
Ok Player 2, Guess a letter! GO!!!
 e
"he_ o _ _ "
You're getting somewhere! Keep trying!
Ok Player 2, Guess a letter! GO!!!
 l
"hel o _ _ "
You're getting somewhere! Keep trying!
"hello _ _ "
```

When the user guesses the word, it does not put my "congrats" statement and end the game.

I am also stuck on my 'lose' method. I am not sure how to fix the method so that the game ends when the user runs out of attempts and prints the "lose" statement.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making the output too complicated. I would track the word and the guesses in an array. Instead of a `display_word` variable, I'd make it a method, possibly "to_s"

By the way, Ruby convention is to use CamelCase class names.

```
class WordGame
  def initialize(word)
    @word = word.downcase.chars
    @guesses = ["_"] * @word.size
  end

  def to_s
    @guesses.join " "
  end
```

This should fix your spacing problem. This will also simplify guesses.

Also, the checking to see if you've already used the letter should probably be handled by the WordGame class.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, your `@display_word` starts as follows:

```
[0] = '_' # For h
[1] = ' '
[2] = '_' # For e
[3] = ' '
...
```

When you guess `'e'`, for instance, you do:

```
@display_word[index] = word_guess
```

Where `index` equals 1, the second character in `"hello"`, so as you can see it doesn't write to the `'e'` index in `@display_word`.

For your second problem, there are a number of ways to fix it. For instance, I would do something like using `@attempts_remaining` starting from a value of 10 or so, then using the existing code:

```
if !@word.include? (word_guess)
  @attempts_remaining -= 1  # Count failure to guess
  puts "Nope, guess again..."
end
```

Then:

```
def win? 
  # If you've guessed all the letters, there's no '_' left in the display word
  if !@display_word.include? ('_')
    puts "Congratulations you won!!! You are the word master!!!"
    true
  else
    false
  end
end 

def lose?
  if @attempts_remaining == 0 
    puts "You lose!!"
    true 
  end 
end
```

Finally, tweak the `until` loop termination condition:

```
until game.win? or game.lose?
```

The existing calls to `win?` and `lose?` can be deleted.

Comment: Thank you so much! I do get the win method to work... however, even though it ends I get the error message 'unexpected return' for the last bit of code you put.

Comment: Also, in changing my current !@word.include? part... when I run the code, if I input an 'incorrect' letter, "nope guess again" prints out 5 times and it just immediately ends the game with "you lose". I am not sure why this happened.

Comment: Disregard my last comment! I had it defined inside the do block and once I defined it outside of that it stopped printing a bunch of times and let me continue guessing. The issue with the first comment I still haven't figured out however.

Comment: @BrittFlowers Oops, my mistake! I've changed my answer to have a better set `until` condition.

Answer (score -2):

(WORD MISSING GAME)

puts "                                    "
puts          "*Total Round*"
puts "     "
puts "=> [Round-One ,Round-two,Round -three Round-four]"
puts "                                "
puts "=> [TOTAL 5 Tries]"
puts "                                "
one=""
two=""
three=""
four=""
puts "                                "
puts " --ROUND One press-- => (1)"
one=gets.to_i
puts '==================='
puts "Question:=>  ( K ? N G )"
puts ""
c=5
5.times do
string1 = 'i'
stringone ="I"
puts "Answer:=>  Try NO:#{c}*"
string2 = gets.chomp
if (string1==string2)
puts "*Good Work correct spaling*"
break
elsif (stringone == string2 )
puts "*Good Work correct spaling*"
break
else
puts "-Worng spaling-"
end
c -=1
end
puts "   *Round Over*  "
if c<1
puts " *Tries Over Game End* "
exit
end
puts '==================='
puts "--ROUND Two press-- => (2)"
two=gets.to_i
puts '==================='
puts "Question:=>  (P L ? Y )"
5.times do
string1 = 'a'
stringone = "A"
puts "Answer:=>  Try NO:#{c}*"
string2 = gets.chomp
if (string1==string2)
puts "*Good Work correct spaling*"
break
elsif (stringone==string2)
puts "*Good Work correct spaling*"
break
else
puts "-Worng spaling-"
end
c -=1
if c<1
puts " *Tries Over Game End* "
exit
end
end
puts "   *Round Over*  "

```
puts '==================='
puts "--ROUND Three press-- => (3)"
three=gets.to_i
puts '==================='
puts "Question:=>  ( S P ? T )"
5.times do
string1 = 'o' 
stringone= 'O'
puts "Answer:=>  Try NO:#{c}*"
string2 = gets.chomp
if (string1==string2)
puts "_Good Work correct spaling_"
 break
 elsif (stringone == string2)
puts "_Good Work correct spaling_"
break
else
 puts "-Worng spaling-"
end
c -=1
if c<1
puts " *Tries Over Game End* "
exit
end
end
puts "   *Round Over*  "
puts '==================='
puts "--ROUND Four press-- => (4)"
four=gets.to_i
puts '==================='
puts "Question:=>  ( G ? M E )"
5.times do
string1 = 'a' 
stringone = "A"
puts "Answer:=>  Try NO:#{c}*"
string2 = gets.chomp
if (string1==string2)
puts "_Good Work correct spaling_"
 break
 elsif (stringone == string2)
puts "_Good Work correct spaling_"
  break
else
 puts "-Worng spaling-"
end
c -=1
if c<1
puts " *Tries Over Game End* "
exit
end
end
puts "**Yahoo Congragualtion complete All Round**"
```